# Azure Speaker Recognition Region Restrictions

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I would like to try using the Speaker Recognition service offered on the Azure platform in a hobbyist project, though being quite new to the platform I am unsure if I am able to access it.   The [infomation page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/speech-services/) states that it is only avalible in the WestUS region and since I am in the UK, does this make me unable to access it?

I have been able to set up a Cognitive Services instance in the westUS region, though I'm not sure if this is refering to the same "region" as is required.

Comment: The resource(the instance you created) would be present(deployed) in the West US region. That means, all your API calls would have to hit the west us region, instead of your local region(uk). This might cause your API calls to have some bit of latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, currently, Speaker Recognition only supports Azure Speech resources created in the westus region. You need to have a resource in westus region to use Speaker Recognition service.